# The trait bound io::Error: Clone is not satisfied when implementing a custom error enum

Tags: enums, rust, traits

I am receiving the following error when implementing a custom error type:

```
the trait bound `std::io::Error: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
```

Here is my custom error enum:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::io;
use crate::memtable::Memtable;

// Define our error types. These may be customized for our error handling cases.
// Now we will be able to write our own errors, defer to an underlying error
// implementation, or do something in between.
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum MemtableError {
    Io(io::Error),
    FromUTF8(std::string::FromUtf8Error),
    NotFound,
}

// Generation of an error is completely separate from how it is displayed.
// There's no need to be concerned about cluttering complex logic with the display style.
//
// Note that we don't store any extra info about the errors. This means we can't state
// which string failed to parse without modifying our types to carry that information.
impl fmt::Display for MemtableError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Some error occurred!");
        Ok(())
    }
}

// a test function that returns our error result
fn raises_my_error(memtable: Memtable, key: String) -> Result<(),MemtableError> {
    match memtable.read(key) {
        Ok(v) => Ok(()),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried following these examples:

1. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/multiple_error_types/define_error_type.html
2. https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/e7.custom_error_types.html
3. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/multiple_error_types/wrap_error.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your MemtableError-enum you use `std::io::error` [which does not implement `Clone`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24135). That's what the error message is saying. You should also get the same error about `std::string::FromUtf8Error`.

To solve this issue you can either remove `Clone` from your derive-macro. Or you need to explicitly implement Clone on your error-type. This however wont work in the current setup, because io::Error uses a trait object (`Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>`) internally. And this trait object cannot be cloned. See this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24135). A workaround would be to put `std::io::Error` and `std::string::FromUtf8Error` in a `Rc` or `Arc`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum MemtableError {
    Io(std::rc::Rc<io::Error>),
    FromUTF8(std::rc::Rc<std::string::FromUtf8Error>),
    NotFound,
}
```

To see if this is a reasonable way to solve this issue we need to know more about the rest of your code.

So, the easiest fix is to remove `Clone`. Otherwise work with `Rc`/`Arc`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you're attempting to derive a `Clone` implementation for `MemtableError`, but `std::io::Error` (the type of one of the values that your `MemtableError` can store) doesn't implement `Clone` itself. If cloning isn't required, I'd change it to simply be `#[derive(Debug)]`. Otherwise, we'll need more context on your use case to suggest a more specific fix.